# Google maps Функция не принимает координаты

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Если задавать координаты (41.085,29.06) в самой функции `initMap`, то карта с координатами в Google maps отображаются корректно.

```
<div id="map" class="map-responsive"></div>
<script>
function initMap() {
var uluru = {lat: 41.085, lng: 29.06};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 15,
center: uluru
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: uluru,
map: map
});
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDBhvQuk4RBY8Ngd9VzNWHBG39dHtGN_Bs&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Но почему не работает, если вызываю функцию с широтой и долготой:

```
 <a href="#" onclick=initMap('41.085','29.06')>link</a>
    function initMap(latit,longit){
    var uluru = {lat: latit, lng: longit};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить вызов `google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);`.

Рабочий пример:

```css
.map {
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script>
 function initMap(lat, lng) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: position
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick=initMap('41.085','29.06')>Click me</a>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDBhvQuk4RBY8Ngd9VzNWHBG39dHtGN_Bs">
</script>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/globadaniil/ypagynuj/20/)